# How To get screen content of android default screens

Tags: android, homescreen

I am currently trying to draw a line on top of a textview content in android default screen for example., settings screen. it is possible to get content of the screen if that screen belongs to our own application, i want to know how can i get content of device default screen content from my application. as part of  going through few discussion i got if we get the view object of that screen we can able to do that. so is it possible to get the view object of a android default screen? kindly help on how can we achieve this.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by get screen content? Do you want to get reference of the views? Do you want to get the image/snapshot of the current screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so is it possible to get the view object of a android default screen?

No. That app runs in another process. Its objects cannot magically transport themselves to your process.

> i want to know how can i get content of device default screen content from my application

On Android 5.0+, with user permission, you can use the media projection APIs to take screenshots.

Comment: Hi Commonsware, Thanks for your quick reply. you mean to say we can take screenshot of default screen using the media projection api, but from this screen shot how can i draw a line or an arrow to tell the user to click on that item??

Comment: I think we can use View.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); and View.getDrawingCache(); to get the snapshot as bitmap even on older version of Android.

Comment: @androider Actually you can make RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. Put the view you want user to click, then put ImageView with arrow icon on top of it.

Comment: @HendraWD Actually my point is suppose if i want the user to turn on Air plane mode in setting screen, i want to take user to setting screen and i want to draw a arrow mark or some animation on top of that option in android default setting screen, in that case first i want to know the current position of that option in that particular device correct?

Comment: @androider Since the default Android setting screen doesn't belongs to your application, i don't think there is any ways to do that

Comment: @androider: "but from this screen shot how can i draw a line or an arrow to tell the user to click on that item?" -- you can draw on the screenshot. You cannot draw on the other app.